# What is the best solution to populate a table's foreign key from another table with different no. of rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql

**I have the following tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE Countries(
 CoKey SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
 Name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL);


CREATE TABLE Institutions(
 IKey SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
 Name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL, 
 CoKey INT REFERENCES Countries(CoKey));
```

**and CSV file loaded into tmp_table**

```
CREATE TABLE tmp_table (
 AKey VARCHAR(256) PRIMARY KEY, 
 Name VARCHAR(256), 
 Affiliation VARCHAR(256), 
 Country VARCHAR(256), 
 Website VARCHAR(256));
```

Note: tmp_table.Affiliation >> Institutions.name, tmp_table.Country >> Countries.Name

- No. of rows 7000
- No. of Institutions 1452 (Without Duplicates)
- No. of Institutions 4000
- No. of Countries 3900
- No. of Countries 67 (Without Duplicates)

**I tried the following:**

1. I created the Countries table (67 rows Without Duplicates), populate
   it from the tmp_table.
2. I used INSERT INTO + SELECT + FROM to populate the FK in Institutions
   table (1452 rows Without Duplicates) (of course it didn't work because there is a mismatch in the
   no. of rows).

What is the best solution to populate a table's foreign key from another table with different no. of rows?

Comment: You would need to join the `tmp_table` with the countries table to do that. What exactly is the INSERT you tried? (**[edit]** your question and add it, don't add code in comments)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: a limit of 256 for a `varchar` column has no performance (or storage) advantage whatsoever over a limit of e.g. 300, 42 or 217